# Unity, WebSocketSharp Singleton: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: websocket, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have created Singleton with webscoket connection:

```
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;

public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Singleton instance;
    public WebSocket conn ; 

    public static Singleton Instance
    {

        get { 
            return instance ?? (instance = new GameObject("Singleton").AddComponent<Singleton>()); 
        }
    }

    public void Start() {
        WebSocket conn = new WebSocket ("ws://localhost:8080/");
        conn.Connect ();
        conn.Send ("connected");
    }

    public void DoSomeAwesomeStuff()
    {
        conn.Send ("msg 1");
        conn.Send ("msg 2");
        conn.Send ("msg 3");
    }
}
```

But when i'm using it somewhere like that:

```
Singleton.Instance.DoSomeAwesomeStuff ();
```

I receive message "connected" but when lunching DoSomeAwsomeStuff i receive error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i found solution:

```
public void Awake() { //Changed start to Awake
    conn = new WebSocket ("ws://localhost:8080/"); // removed WebSocket on begin
    conn.Connect ();
    conn.Send ("connected");
}
```

now works as expected